# Rename file based on regex filename match

Tags: regex, extract, rename, file-rename, strip

I used `hazel` to automatically rename files and move them into folders - however - it took the wrong date.
I fixed the date on the file with a shell script and exif tools but now need to again rename the files.

Files can be of multiple types e.g.

```
2014-10-29 - _DSF5234.JPG
2014-10-29 - _DSF5234.DNG
2014-10-29 - _DSF5234.PSD
```

and I need to remove the `"2014-10-29 - "` portion from the filename of each file. Ideally it would be a script just processing one file directly and I embed it to the hazel action.

Found this regex `([12]\d{3}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]))`

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Read plesae "How to ask" and use correct `code formating` in your text.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the sample regex you gave, change the capturing groups to non-capturing groups by adding `?:` after the opening parenthesis, adding `-` to match the other characters you want to return/remove, then adding a positive lookahead for the rest of the filename.

```
^([12]\d{3}-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]) - )(?=.+\.\w+$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/N5XweP/1